# numpy arctan2 arguments leads to ValueError depending on syntax

Tags: python, numpy

Code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
y1, y2 = [5, 3]

print(np.arctan2(y1, y2))  # Output: 1.0303768265243125

print(np.arctan2(x1=y1, x2=y2))
# Output:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
#<ipython-input-13-b7d0f788df1f> in <module>()
#----> 1 np.arctan2(x1=y1, x2=y2)

#ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

I cannot explain the ValueError thrown. I'd expect both to be semantically identical. Is that something with Python, Numpy or with my lack of understanding?

This is the definition of [arctan2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#numpy.arctan2) in Numpy:

```
def arctan2(x1, x2, *args, **kwargs)
```

Versions I use:

- Linux-4.13.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
- Python 3.6.1 (default, Jun 16 2017, 16:00:03) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
- NumPy 1.14.2

Comment: Where did you find that `umath.py` file? It doesn't seem to exist in my copy of numpy. As far as I know `arctan2` resides in a computer generated C file.

Comment: I jumped into that with PyCharm. But it seems this file does not exist but is rather generated: The comments on top state ` from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so by generator 1.145 `.  I removed the mentioning of it in the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters `x1` and `x2` are so called [*positional-only* parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/). This is indicated in the `arctan2` documentation by the `/` character in the function signature:

```
numpy.arctan2(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj]) = <ufunc 'arctan2'
                      ^
```

Comment: Which are seldom now (AFAIK mainly mathematical function), and only on functions implemented in C.